# How to set `secure` and `httpOnly` for Plones `__ac` cookie?

Tags: plone, session-cookies, zope

I have Plone 4.3.2 (Zope 2.13.21) installed. As mentioned in the documentation (http://plone.org/documentation/kb/securing-plone) cookies should be `secure` and `httpOnly` with Zope 2.12 or higher.

> Also note that the suggested patch has been included in Zope 2.12.0
>   b1, so Plone 4, which will use Zope 2.12 or higher, won't have this
>   problem

But if I log in as admin (or another user that is defined at zope-root) the `__ac` cookie is not `secure` and not `httpOnly`. If I log in as a user created in a site everything is fine. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Short version: use your front-end web server.  Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193366/according-to-german-bsi-plone-does-not-use-secure-cookies-ootb-how-do-i-change

Comment: I use nginx as front-end server. Can ngnix do something similar like Apaches `Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;Secure;HttpOnly`. Plone docu says that it can not do it but the docu is 5 years old.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/496749/in-nginx-reverse-proxy-how-to-set-the-secure-flag-for-cookies has some discusssion.

Answer (score 0):

First off, to set cookie settings in Plone:

- append /manage onto your plone site url
- click "acl_users"
- click "session"
- click "properties" tab

Then, as for root login, it depends on where you login.

Zope root does not implement a cookie plugin, it only logs in with basic auth. IMO, you should never have zope root accessible without first tunneling or using a VPN to get into it.

Finally, you can disable credentials_basic_auth plugin from your plone site.